# Carrinho de compras (checkout) mantendo apenas o último valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tudo certo?

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com Laravel framework PHP para back-end e jQuery para o front-end. Estou montando um checkout de ingressos para estádios de futebol para um sistema que estou desenvolvendo.

Praticamente já tenho todo o checkout pronto, porém, o que acontece é que se eu volto a `<section>` anterior o valor que ele calcula é o valor do produto que ele adicionou ou seja ele não mantém o valor antigo (o checkout está dividido em 3 etapas).

1 - O usuário seleciona o setor do estádio e se possuir cadeira ele seleciona as cadeiras que deseja, caso seja arquibancada seleciona a arquibancada.

2 - O carrinho de compra com os produtos (Ele está calculando a quantidade de produtos de forma correta mas com base no tipo do setor que é).
O problema está aqui. Resumidamente, eu cliente, adiciono 2 ingressos que estão em um setor que possuem cadeiras mas ai eu volto e adiciono mais 1 ingresso que é arquibancada, se eu voltar ao meu carrinho ele vai calcular com base no preço da arquibancada e não mais no preço das cadeiras.

Print demonstrativo: http://prntscr.com/l5hj5v

Em meu jQuery, eu estou separando os valores e ele está calculando com base na resposta que vem de um AJAX do meu banco de dados. Na pratica, o valor que ele deveria trazer seria 250,00 pois em meu banco de dados uma cadeira custa 100,00 e um ingresso pra arquibancada é 50,00. Mas ele trás apenas o último e o valor da cadeira é apagado.

3 - Por fim, os dados de pagamento.

Meu jQuey:

```
$('.btn-next a[href=#section-2]').click(function () {
let match = $('input[name=id_match]').val();
let sector = $('select[name=id_sector] :selected').text();
let id_sector = $('select[name=id_sector] :selected').val();

$('.checkbox-success').children('input:checked').each(function () {
    let chair = $(this).val();

    if (chair == ''){ chair = '-'; }

    // Monta a estrutura da tabela do carrinho de compras
    $.get('/api/checkout', {
        match: match,
    },
    function (data) {
        $('#data-cart').append(`
            <tr>
                <td><p class="text-center">` + data['lot']['id'] + `</p></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <img src="` + data['photo_club_main'] + `" style="height: 80px;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <img src="http://elotorcedor.local:8000/images/versus.svg" style="height: 40px;margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 20px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <img src="` + data['photo_club_visitor'] + `" style="height: 80px;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span class="col-md-12">` + data['championship'] + `</span>
                        <span class="col-md-12"><b>` + data['club_main'] + ' X ' + data['club_visitor'] + `</b></span>
                        <span class="col-md-12">` + data['stadium'] + ` - ` + data['date_match'] + `</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><span id="ticket-reserved" class="text-center">` + chair + `</span></td>
                <td><span id="sector-selected" class="text-center">` + sector + `</span></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="option_half" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Não</option>
                        <option value="2">Sim</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        `);
    });

    $.get('/api/lot', {
        match: match,
        sector: id_sector,
    },
    function (data) {
        let elo_balance  = 80.00;
        let price_full = data['price_full'];
        let amount_chair =  $('.checkbox-success').children('[data-type=chair]:checked').size();
        let amount_grandstand =  $('.checkbox-success').children('[data-type=grandstand]:checked').size();

        if (amount_chair != 0) {
            var total = price_full * amount_chair;
        }
        if (amount_grandstand != 0) {
            var total = price_full * amount_grandstand;
        }

        var amount_pay = total - elo_balance;

        $('#amount-full').empty();
        $('#amount-pay').empty();
        $('#elo-balance').empty();

        $('#amount-full').append('<span class="money">R$ ' + total + '</span>');
        $('#elo-balance').append('<span>Saldo EloTorcedor: <b>R$ ' + elo_balance + '</b></span>');
        $('#amount-pay').append('<span class="text-success"><b>R$ ' + amount_pay + '</b></span>');

        $('.btn-next a[href=#section-3]').click(function () {
            let request = [

            ];
        });
    });
});
```

});

Ficou meio longo mas acho que ficou bem clara a ideia e o problema que está acontecendo :x

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz ou um caminho pra corrigir agradecerei!
Valeu galera ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (amount_chair != 0) {
        var total = price_full * amount_chair;
    }
    if (amount_grandstand != 0) {
        var total = price_full * amount_grandstand;
    }
```

Acredito que o problema esteja aqui. Se amount_grandstand não for 0, o valor total é definido apenas por price_full * amount_grandstand, sem levar em consideração amount_chair.
Se esse for o caso, você não precisa de if para calcular o total, apenas utilize

```
var total = (price_full * amount_chair) + (price_full * amount_grandstand);
```

**Alternativamente**

Se o número de ingressos está correto, e apenas a base está errado, então a culpa é do price_full. Ambos ingressos para cadeiras e arquibancada são multiplicados por price_full, o que significa que ambos vão ser calculados como se tivessem o mesmo valor.
Para corrigir esse problema, retorne o valor para cadeiras e arquibancada separadamente do seu back end, e então multiplique esses valores por amount_chair e amount_grandstand devidamente.

Comment: Eai! Eu testei e realmente não tinha a necessidade desses dois IFs hehe, obrigado pela dica. Mas infelizmente o problema do valor ainda acontece :/

Comment: @Tiago Paza, editei a resposta, tente novamente.

Comment: Editei meu back-end e montei o JSON que deve retornar pro meu front-end assim: https://ideone.com/I1lXqB e em meu front alterei como você falou pra receber: https://ideone.com/cEKla3 Tenho certeza que é algo bem tosco que eu estou errando, mas não sei o que kk

Comment: Isso é porque no seu código PHP, você só está retornando devidamente o preço das cadeiras, ou das arquibancadas, e retornando 0 para a outra.
Você precisa retornar ambos os preços das cadeiras e das arquibancadas, ou então se você comprar um ingresso para ambos, as cadeiras serão multiplicadas pelo preço correto, e as arquibancadas serão multiplicadas por 0.

Comment: Alterei mas mesmo assim trouxe errado... https://pastebin.com/LQBP2xJ2